# How to work with a classpath resource in FXML to stay compatible with SceneBuilder?

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

When i'm using an image in my FXML code like this...

```
<Image url="@/de/myprj/assets/icons/arrow.png" />
```

...everything goes fine until the moment when i want to edit the FXML file in SceneBuilder. How can i use such resources within FXML with SceneBuilder?

Comment: Try `File -> Import -> Media` in SceneBuilder

Comment: This is working, but it results in SceneBuilder to use an absolute path to the image. In my project, i have to use resources out of another library in my classpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is far safer to set the image using CSS, either in scene builder or preferably in a stylesheet specific to your app.

Checkout: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#imageview

**edit:**

Create a css file, load it into the scene's css files when you start your application.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(new File("mycss.css").toURI().toString());
```

In your CSS file add the following:

```
.the-image {
    -fx-image: url("theimage.png");
}
```

Make sure there is a file called theimage.png in the same directory as your css file.  In scenebuilder, click on the ImageView.  In the box that is labeled "Style Class" add the string the-image.

Voila.

Comment: What i'm doing is to utilize the substructure of a ´TitledPane´ to show the image in the header on the right side as it is an ´HBox´. As i'm not very familiar with CSS so far, i'd need to know how to achieve this via CSS to follow your advise.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, does it? How can you see the changes in SceneBuilder? This solution just moves the problem to "how to attach classpath-relative css in a SceneBuilder compatible way".